# threadable delay in python 2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, delay, flags

I'm currently using python (2.7) to write a GUI that has some threads going on. I come across a point that I need to do a roughly about a second delay before getting a piece of information, but I can't afford to have the function takes more than a few millisecond to run. With that in mind, I'm trying to create a Threaded timer that will set a flag `timer.doneFlag`  and have the main function to keep poking to see whether it's done or not.

It is working. But not all the time. The problem that I run into is that sometimes I feel like the `time.sleep` function in `run` , doesn't wait fully for a second (sometimes it may not even wait). All I need is that I can have a flag that allow me control the start time and raise the flag when it reaches 1 second.

I maybe doing too much just to get a delay that is threadable, if you can suggest something, or help me find a bug in the following code, I'd be very grateful!

I've attached a portion of the code I used:

from main program:

```
class dataCollection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer=Timer(5)
        self.isTimerStarted=0  
        return

    def StateFunction(self): #Try to finish the function within a few milliseconds

        if self.isTimerStarted==0:
           self.timer=Timer(1.0)
           self.timer.start()
           self.isTimerStarted=1

        if self.timer.doneFlag:
           self.timer.doneFlag=0
           self.isTimerStarted=0
           #and all the other code



import time
import threading
class Timer(threading.Thread):          
    def __init__(self, seconds):            
        self.runTime = seconds          
        self.doneFlag=0
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):      
        time.sleep(self.runTime)    
        self.doneFlag=1
        print "Buzzzz"

x=dataCollection()
while 1:
    x.StateFunction()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Your code starts with `def StateFunction(self)` (without indentation), but there is no class definition before that. Could you post the complete code with the correct indentation?

Comment: ok, let's say above is my code. My actual code in this file is more than 1000 lines and don't want to disclosure for a reason or another.

Comment: Almost this exact same thing is already built in to the stdlib: [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects).

Comment: Also, as a side note, why are you using `0` and `1` for a flag instead of `False` and `True`? You have to read through the code and figure out if you've got additional values besides 0 or 1, and whether you're using the 0=False/1=True convention or the nonzero=False/zero=True one, and so on.

Comment: Thank you abarnert. That was some really good feedback. I'll take a look of the threading.Timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've effectively rebuilt [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) with less flexibility. So I think you're better off using the existing class. (There are some obvious downsides with creating a thread for each timer instance. But if you just want a single one-shot timer, it's fine.)

More importantly, having your main thread repeatedly poll `doneFlag` is probably a bad idea. This means you have to call your state function as often as possible, burning CPU for no good reason.

Presumably the reason you have to return within a few milliseconds is that you're returning to some kind of event loop, presumably for your GUI (but, e.g., a network reactor has the same issue, with the same solutions, so I'll keep things general).

If so, almost all such event loops have a way to schedule a timed callback within the event loop—`Timer` in `wx`, `callLater` in `twisted`, etc. So, use that.

If you're using a framework that doesn't have anything like that, it hopefully at least has some way to send an event/fire a signal/post a message/whatever it's called from outside. (If it's a simple file-descriptor-based reactor, it may not have that, but you can add it yourself just by tossing a pipe into the reactor.) So, change your `Timer` callback to signal the event loop, instead of writing code that polls the `Timer`.

If for some reason you really *do* need to poll a variable shared across threads, you really, really, should be protecting it with a `Condition` or `RLock`. There is no guarantee in the language that, when thread 0 updates the value, thread 1 will see the new value immediately, or even *ever*. If you understand enough of the internals of (a specific version of) CPython, you can often prove that the GIL makes a lock unnecessary in specific cases. But otherwise, this is a race.

Finally:

> The problem that I run into is that sometimes I feel like the time.sleep function in run , doesn't wait fully for a second (sometimes it may not even wait).

Well, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) clearly says this can happen:

> The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine.

So, if you need a guarantee that it actually sleeps for at least 1 second, the only way to do this is something like this:

```
t0 = time.time()
dur = 1.0
while True:
    time.sleep(dur)
    t1 = time.time()
    dur = 1.0 - (t1 - t0)
    if dur <= 0:
        break
```